# CS0029 Cannot convert Type to Type with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net

This is a recurring theme. I'm trying to return an object (in this case a list of NpiResponseModel) with JsonConvert, what would be the proper way to do this?  In the below scenario I receive that cannot convert type NpiResponseModel to Generic.List.  Thanks!

```cs
public List<NpiResponseModel> LookupByNpiNumber(NpiRequestModel npiRequest)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/");
    var request = new RestRequest("?");
    request.AddParameter("version", "2.1");
    request.AddParameter("number", npiRequest.Number);
    request.AddParameter("enumeration_type", "NPI-1");
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;
    var nppsResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NpiResponseModel>(content);
    return nppsResults;
}
```

I've attempted to explicitly convert it to an object, creating the object first and doing npiResponse.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content)). This is a recurring issue for me and knowing how to do it properly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're explicitly converting to *one* `NpiResponseModel`, but your method is declared to return `List<NpiResponseModel>`. How do you expect to get a list to return? (If you only want to return a single object, why is your method declared to return a list?)

Comment: Is the content returned from the call a list or an object?

Comment: If your JSON is *actually* a list, then deserialize to that: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NpiResponseModel>>(content)`

Comment: Use in build library in .Net System.Text.Json For Deserialization.

Comment: @Maherotti: That doesn't feel like a particularly helpful suggestion to me. Nothing in this question suggests that the problem is with Json.NET, and converting this code to the equivalent in System.Text.Json would leave the OP with *exactly* the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are deserializing into a single `NpiResponseModel` item, but your method return type is `List<NpiResponseModel>`.

The fix depends on what the actual content payload represents... is it a List of NpiResponseModel items? Or just a single one?

If it is a list, then change the Deserialize statement to be `.DeserializeObject<List<NpiResponseModel>>(content)` and that should fix the error.
Otherwise, if the content is a single item, then wrap the deserialized nppsResults in a List before returning.  Example: `return new List<NpiResponseModel> { nppsResults };`

Comment: It finally dawned on my that I was trying to deserialize to a single object instead of a list of objects.  Thank you